# Set a UIButton to the size of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom class for `UICollectionViewCell` called `ChronicleCell`.

I am creating an instance variable of type, `UIButton`.

```
 class ChronicleCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    //init etc.
    var buttonFullCellSize : UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        //TODO set button to be size of UICollectionViewCell frame

    }()

 }
```

For this instance variable, I would like to set its frame to be equivalent to the `UICollectionViewCell`'s frame. However this is not accessible in a class that inherits from `UICollectionViewCell`. How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at accessing `self.contentView` to get all the size info of the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell's `contentView` is the same size as the cell so you should use this to get the frame.

```
var buttonFullCellSize: UIButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = contentView.frame
    return button
}
```

Comment: @Allanah_Douglas when I write that within my ChronicleCell class I get the following error `Instance member 'contentView' cannot be used on type 'ChronicleCell'`

Comment: Ah but i think that is because i am trying to access class properties within a closure!

Answer (score 2):

Assign the collectionViewLayout's frame to the button's:

```
let rect = self.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(clIndexPath).frame
button.frame = button.rect
```

Your code may be :

```
 class ChronicleCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    //init etc.
    var buttonFullCellSize : UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
       let frameOfUICollectionViewCell = self.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(clIndexPath).frame
       button.frame = button.rect
       return button
    }()

 }
```